# Extracting HTML text

Tags: c#, html

I am working on a problem. I am going to extract som HTML text and store them as Anchor object. For example:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>{dynamihead/}</title>
</head>

<body>
{repeatinghtml}
<p>{repeatinganchor1/}</p>
<p>{repeatinganchor2/}</p>
<p>{repeatinganchor3/}</p>
<p>{repeatinganchor4/}</p>
{/repeatinghtml}
</body>
</html>
```

I want to extract the {} anchor. If its a selfterminating achour i want to create {dynamihead/} just this anchor object. But if its contain childAnchours i want to extract like

```
{repeatinghtml}
    <p>{repeatinganchor1/}</p>
    <p>{repeatinganchor2/}</p>
    <p>{repeatinganchor3/}</p>
    <p>{repeatinganchor4/}</p>
{/repeatinghtml}
```

i want to extract all the child anchours and put the in a collection in the main anchor. I have defiend the Anchor class, but i im not so skilled at string handling so im having trouble extracting the text that i want. This is a winform application that is going to load a template hmlt file, proccess it and instert information into the ancours and the send a email i html format.

Comment: I think you can use Regex to extract the string or XDocument

Answer (score 1):

Try to look at [HtmlAgility](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) library. Even if it looks simpler at a first glance there is a [lot of reasons to avoid using regex for such problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/566608), and eighter string manipulation will probably not suffice.

Comment: i have tried using HtmlAgility library without any luck. Pherhaps i used i wrong but i tried to follow some examples without luck.